# Почему @OneToMany не грузит коллекции в LAZY?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Изучаю для себя LAZY loading, думал, что коллекция должна быть NULL, пока ее явно не попросят загрузиться.

Вот пример с Restaurant Entity ( методы пропущены для краткости, оставил только toString)

```
public class Restaurant extends AbstractNamedEntity {

    String address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) 
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Dish> dishes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Vote> votes;
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Restaurant{" +
            "address='" + address + '\'' +
            ", dishes=" + dishes +
            ", votes=" + votes +
            '}';
}
}
```

Сначала загружаю объект Vote, который в себе имеет ссылку на Restaurant и получаю его.
Т.е.

```
Vote vote = voteRepository.getById(1);
Restaurant restaurant = Vote.getRestaurant();
System.out.println(restaurant);
```

И выходит такое

```
Restaurant{address='Эспланада, 2а', dishes=[Dish{price=80.0, dateAdded=2021-08-13 };, Dish{price=69.0, dateAdded=2021-08-13 };], votes=[ voteDate=2021-08-13, user=restaurant.entity.User@22}]}
```

Т.е. несмотря, что дефолтный fetch type у @OneToMany lazy, все коллекции загружены. Почему? Разве не смысл lazy в том, что они должны быть NULL, пока я не сделаю restaurant.getDishes() явно.

Ладно, допустим, что это особенность получения объекта, из другого объекта, который имеет ссылку на него.
Но если написать напрямую

```
 Restaurant restaurant =  restaurantRepository.getById(1);
System.out.println(restaurant);
```

то результат не меняется. Все коллекции будут загружены при System.out.println(). Буду крайне благодарен тому, кто сможет доступно объяснить почему так.

P.S. результат не меняется, даже если fetchType указан явно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что LAZY loading начинает подгружать сущности сразу как вы обратились к списку. А это вы делаете в методе `toString()`

Comment: Понял, а как можно наглядно посмотреть, что подгрузилось? ToString ведь не подходит.
Изначально я начал смотреть это все, потому что хотел узнать, когда я обращаюсь к объекту restaurant, который загрузил через vote.getRestaurant(), он загружается со всеми полями или lazy даже при таком методе получения объекта тоже работает.

Comment: Можете включить опцию Hibernate чтобы он печатал SQL запрос который генерит, так косвенно будет понятно что подгружается (если у вас проект spring boot это `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`)